# MVC - how do I know on what page I am (both at Client and Server level)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Imagine i have a control (or partial view) that needs to display differently depending on what page it is.

How can I know both at the Server and Client level on what page I am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server (ASP.NET & MVC):

```
Request.Url
```

On the client using Javascript:

```
window.location
```